# Powershell - Capture cmd-let error to variable

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to capture error from command into variable and to exit script if error occures

```
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity Office@example.com -Member `
tony.stark@example.com -ErrorAction stop -ErrorVariable MyError `
if ($MyError.Count -gt 0) {`
exit

}
```

But MyError variable is empty and script continues to run,

if however, specify `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` then script simply continues and error variable is empty

Comment: is there a reason NOT to use try/catch?

Comment: yes, this code is already included in one bigger try/catch

Comment: You can nest `try`/`catch`, so could wrap the call to `Add-DistributionGroupMember` in its own one that exits if it catches anything.

Comment: the try/catch construct is not intended for big chunks of code. [*grin*] if you have a large chunk of code wrapped in a single try/catch ... you are doing it wrong. the construct is designed for catching errors as they happen ... not for "oh, look, and error happened somewhere" situations.

Comment: ok, i'll try with try/catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment, you should use a nested `try catch block` for the specified cmdlet, like this:

```
try
{
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity Office@example.com -Member `
tony.stark@example.com -ErrorAction stop -ErrorVariable MyError `
}
catch {
      if($MyError.Count -gt 0)
      {
        Write-Output $myerror

        #if you want to exit execution after this error, use exit command as blow
        exit
      }
      }
```